# Disabling horizontal scroll via touch in an iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I have an iframe on a website that I would like to disable horizontal (not vertical) scrolling in, specifically when the user activates a touch input on the website and drags horizontally (that is, it's okay if the scroll bars are still visible and draggable by touching them directly). I have no control over the website that is showing in the iframe, unfortunately.

I've looked around this site and it seems either really difficult or not possible. I've tried:

- putting `scrolling=no` as an iframe attribute (this turns off both scrollbars and I need to keep vertical)
- adding `overflow-x: hidden` as a style to the iframe (this does nothing)

I will be controlling this iframe primarily on a large display using touch controls, and it's okay if it only works for touch (is there a way I can manually override some sort of touch event and detect if they are trying to horizontally scroll the iframe?). I only need to support the latest version of Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It would be hard to check without a link but perhaps you can look into CSS `pointer-events: none;` Or any other pointer-events.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to disable some touch events individually, but you can't prevent scrolling in an iframe on a single axis without doing some hacks. The `scrolling=no` attribute was deprecated in HTML5.

The best solution is simply to set the width of the iframe <= the width of the src page.

Comment: We do currently capture the entire visible website, but unfortunately the site we are iframe-ing has an invisible HTML element somewhere in the background which artificially pushes the page out horizontally and causes scroll bars to appear. I do agree with your solution in principle but it won't work for us in this case without making our iframe very wide and causing tons of white space issues.